# libllhttp-ext.bundle (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64h' or 'x86_64'))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, ffi, bootsnap, lib-http

I am using macbook pro 2019 running sonoma 14.3.1 (23D60)
when I install gems via bundle install, all the gems get installed correctly but on rails s or rails c, I get

```
(called from <main> at /Users/macbookpro/upwork/solaris/solaris-cloud/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-467517368502/lib/active_admin.rb:2)
/Users/macbookpro/upwork/solaris/solaris-cloud/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/lib/ffi/dynamic_library.rb:65:in `load_library': Could not open library '/Users/macbookpro/upwork/solaris/solaris-cloud/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/llhttp-ffi-0.5.0/ext/aarch64-darwin/libllhttp-ext.bundle': dlopen(/Users/macbookpro/upwork/solaris/solaris-cloud/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/llhttp-ffi-0.5.0/ext/aarch64-darwin/libllhttp-ext.bundle, 0x0005): tried: '/Users/macbookpro/upwork/solaris/solaris-cloud/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/llhttp-ffi-0.5.0/ext/aarch64-darwin/libllhttp-ext.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64h' or 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/macbookpro/upwork/solaris/solaris-cloud/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/llhttp-ffi-0.5.0/ext/aarch64-darwin/libllhttp-ext.bundle' (no such file), '/Users/macbookpro/upwork/solaris/solaris-cloud/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/llhttp-ffi-0.5.0/ext/aarch64-darwin/libllhttp-ext.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64h' or 'x86_64')). (LoadError)
Searched in <system library path>, /usr/lib, /usr/local/lib, /opt/local/lib
```

I have tried reinstalling xcode developer tools, I have also updated cocoapods

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and for some reason, `bundler` installs both versions (`arm64` and `x86_64`) of `llhttp-ffi-0.5.0`, without being able to pick the right file:

```
$ bundle install
...
$ ls -l ./vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/llhttp-ffi-0.5.0/ext/                                                                            total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 username  staff  113 Feb 26 11:38 Rakefile
drwxr-xr-x  4 username  staff  128 Feb 26 11:38 aarch64-darwin
drwxr-xr-x  8 username  staff  256 Feb 26 11:38 llhttp
drwxr-xr-x  4 username  staff  128 Feb 26 11:38 x86_64-darwin
$
```

There's probably a cleaner way to address this, but removing the `aarch64-darwin` fixed it for me:

```
$ rm -rf ./vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/llhttp-ffi-0.5.0/ext/aarch64-darwin
```

Note, the previous version (`llhttp-ffi-0.4.0`) had the only the file that matched with my architecture installed so the problem wasn't visible:

```
$ ls -l ./vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/llhttp-ffi-0.4.0/ext                                                                            
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 username  staff  113 Feb 26 11:43 Rakefile
drwxr-xr-x  8 username  staff  256 Feb 26 11:43 llhttp
drwxr-xr-x  4 username  staff  128 Feb 26 11:43 x86_64-darwin
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works for me! I only needed to change the path example:

rm -rf ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/llhttp-ffi-0.5.0/ext/aarch64-darwin

then i ran rails c and it works fine!

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the project you're working on came with bundled gems, ie. they were prebuilt, and looks like they were prebuilt for "Apple silicon" and you have Intel. Delete the `vendor/bundle` directory and try re-running your `bundle install`.